# Simultanious button touch on simulator

Tags: xcode

Is it at all possible to test something similar to "hold shift" while touching other buttons?

I know I can perform all gestures, but 'click-hold' one button, and clicking another button? It does not seems to be on the simulator function list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Check out apple's documentation (Simulating User Gestures section): 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH3-SW3

These are the supported gestures:

- Tap
- Touch and hold
- Double-tap
- Drag
- Swipe
- Flick
- Two-finger Drag
- Pinch
- Rotate

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but wanted to be sure it wasn't some 'hidden feature'.